# Form won't post when in NATIVE mode

Tags: google-apps-script

Could anyone explain to me why the following code would NOT post when in NATIVE sandbox mode? When it's in EMULATED mode it works.

**Code.gs**

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index.html');
  template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();

  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log("TESTING!");
}
```

**Index.html**

```html
<form action="<?= action ?>" method="post">
  <label>Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"></label><br>
  <label><input type="submit"></label>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the console output in chrome?

Comment: Nothing...empty :(...could you duplicate it in Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

The form won't post because it gets the `onsubmit='return false'` attribute after the caja sanatizing. If you remove it then it works as expected:

You can remove it with jQuery for example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var form = $('#form');
  form.removeAttr('onsubmit');
</script>
```

Tested and working. complete code below:

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index.html');
  template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();

  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(e);
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('thanks.html');
  template.phone = e.parameter.phone;
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  }
```

**index.html**

```
<form id='form' action="<?= action ?>" method="POST">
  <label>Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"></label><br>
  <label><input type="submit"></label>
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var form = $('#form');
  form.removeAttr('onsubmit');
</script>
```

**thanks.html**

```
<div>
Thanks,
You entered <?= phone ?>!
</div>
```

Comment: Why does it get the onsubmit='return false' attribute after the caja sanatizing in NATIVE mode and not EMULATED mode? Any idea?

Comment: You don't need to bring in jQuery, just do: `document.getElementById("form").removeAttribute("onsubmit");`